# F# Seq.initInfinite giving StackOverflowException

Tags: f#

I'm learning F#, and I am having trouble understanding why this crashes. It's an attempt to solve [Project Euler problem 2](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=2).

```
let rec fibonacci n =
    if n = 1 then
        1
    elif n = 2 then
        2
    else
        fibonacci (n - 1) + fibonacci (n - 2)

let debugfibonacci n =
    printfn "CALC: %d" n
    fibonacci n

let isEven n =
    n % 2 = 0

let isUnderLimit n =
    n < 55

let getSequence =
    //[1..30]
    Seq.initInfinite (fun n -> n)
    |> Seq.map debugfibonacci
    |> Seq.filter isEven
    |> Seq.takeWhile isUnderLimit

Seq.iter (fun x -> printfn "%d" x) getSequence
```

The final version would call a sum function (and would have a higher limit than 55), but this is learning code.

As is, this gives a StackOverflowException. However, if I comment in the [1..30] and comment out the Seq.initInfinite, I get:

```
CALC: 1
CALC: 2
2
CALC: 3
CALC: 4
CALC: 5
8
CALC: 6
CALC: 7
CALC: 8
34
CALC: 9
CALC: 10
CALC: 11
```

It appears to be generating items on demand, as I would expect in LINQ. So why does it blow up when used with initInfinite?

Comment: +1 for generating StackOverflowException

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Seq.initInfinite` returns a sequence that starts at `0`.

Your `fibonacci` function results in a stack overflow when called with zero, because it never hits the terminating cases.

You can solve this by starting from `Seq.initInfinite (fun n -> n + 1)`

Comment: Aargh! Thank you!! I also found that putting the takeWhile before the filter would cut down on the number of iterations.

Answer (score 7):

You're starting with 0 with `initInfinite`, which then recurses -1, -2, ...

(By the way, if you're using the Visual Studio debugger, this is easy to diagnose, by checking the call stack and locals window.)